# PHP SOAP Server not working

Tags: c#, php, soap

I have written a SOAP server in PHP using http://code.google.com/p/php-wsdl-creator/downloads/list
My client is in Dynamics CRM Online plugin written in C#
Everything works fine on my testing website, however when I send the SOAP server across to the clients web host, they have uploaded the files, but I'm getting the following error returned:

```
SoapServer::SoapServer(): 'soap_version' option must be SOAP_1_1 or SOAP_1_2
```

I believe this is a configuration issue on their server (they had to install a SOAP module for this) but I don't know where to look/advise to sort this out.

For reference, my C# class references the SOAP server in a web reference. I have added the following line, trying both 11 and 12 but to no avail:

```
soap.SoapVersion = System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapProtocolVersion.Soap11;
```

When I look at the phpinfo page, my test server has the line `'--enable-soap' '--with-xsl=/usr` in the Configure Command section, where as the web hosts version doesn't but it does have the line `/etc/php.d/soap.ini` in Additional .ini files parsed - would this cause any issue? I don't know anything about configuring php servers.

Comment: This is a bad title. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the soap_version option in the SoapServer constructor (PHP). For example:

```
$server = new SoapServer("some.wsdl", array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));
```

Comment: Will try this - may take an hour to get the host to update the file.

Comment: Turns out the SoapServer was defined in 2 places for whatever logic. Cheers

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem within the php-wsdl-createor-framework.
Their patch on https://code.google.com/p/php-wsdl-creator/ was to change line 434 in class.phpwsdl.php

from

```
    // SOAP server options
    $this->SoapServerOptions=Array(
        'soap_version'  =>  SOAP_1_1|SOAP_1_2,
        'encoding'      =>  'UTF-8',
        'compression'   =>  SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT|SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP|9
    );
```

to

```
    // SOAP server options
    $this->SoapServerOptions=Array(
        'soap_version'  =>  (defined('SOAP_1_2'))?SOAP_1_2:SOAP_1_1,
        'encoding'      =>  'UTF-8',
        'compression'   =>  SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT|SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP|9
    )
```

Hope it helps anyone

Comment: This is actually the solution for those who are using [PhpWsdl](https://code.google.com/p/php-wsdl-creator/).